# Group Policy Preferences not showing up in Win2k3

Tags: windows-server-2003

I installed the Client Side Extensions and rebooted the server.  I'm still not seeing Preferences in the Group Policy Object Editor only Software Settings, Windows Settings, and Administrative Templates.

Is there something I missed in order to enable Group Policy Preferences on server 2k3?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use a Windows 2008 or better server (or Vista+ workstation with RSAT) to administer the GPOs with GPP settings. The Win2000 and 2k3 MMC snapins just do not show them.

http://blogs.technet.com/b/danstolts/archive/2009/01/21/installing-and-managing-group-policy-preferences-on-a-windows-server-2003-domain.aspx

Comment: So the win2k3 server should be processing them now, but it just won't display them?  I think I understand  Is there any way to see them as being there besides just checking clients?

Comment: Install the RSAT on a compatible computer.

Comment: @JoshG Yes Win2k3 servers will process them correctly. But you can only view them in Server2008+ or Vista+ with RSAT.

Answer (score -1):

Sorry to disagree with the above, but you can install the Client-side Extensions (KB943729) - this will enable Win2k3 to process GPO preferences.

Comment: To *process* them, not to *edit* them in their GPMC.