# Windows Mapped Drives: GPO vs. login script

Tags: windows, windows-server-2003-r2, group-policy

I'm running Windows 2003 R2 for DC's. The question has come up concerning mapping user's network shares via GPO rather than the tradition login scripts. I've read about updating Windows 2003 server with the 2008 Client Side Extensions so that the Group Policy Preferences (GPP) can be seen and used.
My questions are:

1. Does the CSE update get applied to the Win 2K3 DC's
2. If number one is "No", how do I see and edit the GPP to map the drives?
3. Does the CSE update get applied to the XP client machines as well?
4. If number three is "Yes", will this work for thin-clients?

In the next couple of months, we'll be installing some 2012 servers into the domain.

Any other advice is most welcome.

Comment: advice: don't add new servers to a decade old domain.

Comment: `The question has come up concerning mapping user's network shares via GPO rather than the tradition login scripts.` - Does this mean there's an existing problem?  Or you simply want a _best practice_ or what?  If it isn't broke I would wait until you have the 2012 DCs in place before messing with it.

Comment: @lvlint67 it's a fairly common thing to do...how else would you get your DCs to 2012 in a 2003 environment?

Comment: @lVlint67 that is terrible advice.  However, it can be made better advice by changing it to "don't create new servers with ancient windows versions that are about to be EOL".  Domains age pretty gracefully and rebuilding the entire directory from scratch just because it's old is... not something people are likely to get budget for.

Comment: @FalconMomot not to mention that many times doing a domain migration is *painful* because things that people build their businesses around cannot be easily migrated to a new domain. Things like BizTalk, Exchange, the entire System Center suite, and Lync all come to mind off of the top of my head.

Answer (score 6):

> Does the CSE update get applied to the Win 2K3 DC's

You don't have to install the KB on the DCs. 2k3 domain controllers are capable of pushing GPOs that have 'group policy preferences' in them.

> If number one is "No", how do I see and edit the GPP to map the drives?

You have to have RSAT on a Vista, Server 2008, or better machine. Server 2003 domain controllers will push the GPOs just fine, however, you cannot see them on 2003-era MMC snapins. If you want to play with the new toys, you have to get off of 10 year-old operating systems.

[Group Policy Preferences not showing up in Win2k3](https://serverfault.com/questions/505339/group-policy-preferences-not-showing-up-in-win2k3)

> Does the CSE update get applied to the XP client machines as well?

You need to ensure that all XP and 2003 clients have the update installed.

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=3628

> If number three is "Yes", will this work for thin-clients?

Yes, you can use group policies on thin clients.

Answer (score 0):

No changes needed on the Domain controllers.

You just have to deploy CLE as said via script or WSUS.

You can find all the information in the link below.

http://goo.gl/bEKRpv

XMLLite is also needed in the client machines unless SP3 installed or SP2 with IE7.